# In how many ways you can count till N using the numbers <= with N

Tags: algorithm

in how many ways you can sum the numbers less or equal with N to be equal with n. What is the algorithm to solve that?

Example:
lets say that we have

```
n =10;
```

so there are a lot of combinations but for example we can do:

```
1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 = 10
1+2+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=10
1+1+2+1+1+1+1+1+1=10
.....
1+9=10
10=10
8+2=10
```

and so on.

If you think is the Catalan questions, the answer is: the problem seems to be Catalan problem but is not. If you take a look to the results you will see that lets say for N=5 In Catalan algorithm you have 14 possibilities. But in right answer you have 2^4=16 possibilities if you count all, or the Fibonacci array if you keep only the unique combinations. Eg N=5 we have 8 possibilities, so the Catalan algorithm doesn't verify.

This was a question received by me in a quiz done for fun, at that time i thought that the solution is a well known formula, so i lost a lot of time trying to remember it :)
I found 2 solutions for this problem and 1 more if you are considering only the unique combinations. Eg 2+8 is the same as 8+2, you are considering only 1 of them.
So what is the algorithm to solve it?

Comment: Look up "Catalan numbers" or "Bell numbers".

Comment: what have you tried? have you at least solved it for N=1,2,3,4 to get a feel of it? can you solve problems with dynamic programming?

Comment: @UmNyobe: not a dupe. it's a huge jump and not even the solution for this.

Comment: does the order matter or not? the question is unclear. and what do you mean by "There are 2 solutions for this problem and 1 more" ?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath he is describing the catalan number of a number n.

Comment: @UmNyobe: 1) at the moment the question is unclear 2) prove it

Comment: @KarolyHorvath what das_weezul posted is how you reach the `generate_catalan_numbers` in the link.

Comment: since the proof is a crucial step, how can this be a dup? and why is everybody ignoring the fact that the task is underspecified?

Comment: i'll can do the proof if you want.

Comment: Guys the problem is like Catalan number but is not (that why i lost a lot of time trying to remember the formula when i try to solve it in instant mode ) If you solve it you will discover the Fibonacci array if you keep only the unique combinations, or to the solutions that comb(n) = 2^(n-1) if you keep the non-unique combinations. I posted below my answer with the 3 solutions that i discovered.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath - the problem is not the 1 you suggested -it seems to be but is not- try to pay more attention. As you can see i analyzed the problem and i found 3 solutions, so i solved it for 1,2,3,4 ...

Comment: @DanutClapa: "try to pay more attention"... to what exactly?? I have no idea what you're talking about. are you confusing me with someone else? If you read it again you'll see I was the one who gave good advice and warned other commenters.

Comment: @DanutClapa: also, I don't understand what the question is. Now it seems you already had the solutions when you've posted the question.

Comment: @ Karoly Horvath I copy pasted the user and I pasted your by mistake :) - this time i didn't payed attention it seems :)

Comment: @ Karoly Horvath By the way you marked the question as duplicate and it isn't. It isn't the Catalan problem as it seems to be. About the solutions and what is the question for. Yes i had my answers for this, but maybe there are more. My basic intentions was to spread the knowledge. As you can see from the comments a lot of people didn't knew the answers, so then it was a good decision to spread the knowledge, and not a junk post.

Comment: @DanutClapa: in case it's not clear from the comments - I haven't. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261530/i-gave-a-different-close-reason-yet-the-system-lists-me

Comment: If you only count permutations of the summands once. The answer can be found using DP maintaining S(n,k)=#{multisets of natural numbers that sum to n and has maximal element k}. See http://www.ams.org/notices/200109/fea-ahlgren.pdf. If permutations are counted separately you can establish a bijection between binary sequences of length n-1 and summands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the 3 solutions that I fount use Math induction:

solution 1:

```
if n =0 comb =1
if n =1 comb = 1 
if n=2 there are 1+1, 2 comb =2 = comb(0)+comb(1)
if n=3 there are 1+1+1, 1+2, 2+1, 3 comb = 4 = comb(0)+comb(1)+comb(2)
if n=4 there are 1+1+1+1, 1+2+1,1+1+2,2+1+1,2+2,1+3,3+1,4 comb = 8 =comb(0)+comb(1)+comb(2)+comb(3)
```

Now we see a pattern here that says that:

```
at k value we have comb(k)= sum(comb(i)) where i between 0 and k-1
using math induction we can prove it for k+1 that:
comb(k+1)= sum(comb(i)) where is is between 0 and k
```

Solution number 2:

If we pay a little more attention to the solution 1 we can say that:

```
comb(0)=2^0
comb(1)=2^0
comb(2)=2^1
comb(3)=2^2
comb(4)=2^3

comb(k)=2^(k-1)
again using the math induction we can prove that 
comb(k+1)=2^k
```

Solution number 3 (if we keep only the unique combinations) we can see that:

```
comb(0)=1
comb(1)=1
comb(2)= 1+1,2=2
comb(3)= 1+1+1, 1+2, 2+1, 3 we take out 1+2 because we have 2+1 and its the same comb(3)=3
comb(4) = 1+1+1+1, 1+2+1,1+1+2,2+1+1,2+2,1+3,3+1,4, here we take out the 1+2+1,,2+1+1 and 1+3 because we have them but in different order comb(4)= 5.
```

If we continue we can see that:

```
comb(5) = 8
comb(6)=13
```

we now can see the pattern that:

```
comb (k) = comb (k-1) + comb(k-2) the Fibonacci array
again using Math induction we can prove that for k+1
comb(k+1) = comb(k)+comb(k-1)
```

now it's easy to implement those solutions in a language using recursion for 2 of the solutions or just the non recursive method for the solution with 2^k.

And by the way this has serious connections with graph theory (how many sub-graphs you can build starting from a bigger graph - our number N, and sub-graphs being the ways to count )

Amazing isn't it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you need is exactly the number of partitions [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)]. This will be different from the Fibonacci series. For example, as the article says, `comb(5) = 7`, not `8`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. I do not have the solution (yet), but I think this can be done in a divide-and-conquer way. If you think of the problem space as a binary tree, you can generate it like this:

**The root is the whole number n
Its children are floor(n/2) and ceil(n/2)**

**Example:**
*n=5*

```
     5
   /   \
  2     3
 / \   / \
1   1 1   2
         / \
        1   1
```

If you do this recursively, you get a binary tree. If can then traverse the tree in this manner to get all the possible combinations of summing up to n:

```
get_combinations(root_node)
{
   combinations=[]
   combine(combinations, root_node.child_left, root_node.child_right)
}

combine(combinations, nodeA, nodeB)
{
   new_combi = "nodeA" + "+nodeB"
   combinations.add(new_combi)
   if nodeA.has_children(): combinations.add( combine(combinations, nodeA.child_left, nodeA.child_right) + "+nodeB" )
   if nodeB.has_children(): combinations.add( "nodeA+" + combine(combinations, nodeB.child_left, nodeB.child_right) )
   return new_combi
}
```

This is just a draft. Of yourse you don't have to explicitly generate the tree beforehand, but you can do that along the way. Maybe I can come up with a nicer algorithm if I find the time.

**EDIT:**

OK, I didn't quite answer OPs question to the point, but I don't like to leave stuff unfinished, so here I present my solution as a working python program:

```
import math

def print_combinations(n):
    for calc in combine(n):
        line = ""
        count = 0
        for op in calc:
            line += str(int(op))
            count += 1
            if count < len(calc):
                line += "+"
        print line

def combine(n):

    p_comb = []
    if n >= 1: p_comb.append([n])
    if n >1: 
        comb_left = combine(math.floor(n/float(2)))
        comb_right = combine(math.ceil(n/float(2)))
        for l in comb_left:
            for r in comb_right:
                lr_merge = []
                lr_merge.extend(l)
                lr_merge.extend(r)
                p_comb.append(lr_merge)
    return p_comb
```

You can now generate all possible ways of summing up *n* with numbers <= *n*. For example if you want to do that for *n=5* you call this: `print_combinations(5)`

Have fun, be aware though that you run into memory issues pretty fast (dynamic programming to the rescue!) and that you can have equivalent calculations (e.g. 1+2 and 2+1).

Comment: please don't post an answer, if you don't have a solution. we generally accept these kind of posts if nobody was able to tackle the problem for a significant time period...

Comment: you are not exactly replying to the question, but your logic is correct. To reach the dp you need to see that `floor(n/2)` `ceil(n/2)` division is a specific case of a binary tree where for every node n `value(n) = value(left(n)) + = value(right(n))`. How many trees of such type can you build?

Comment: yes, the idea is good use recurrence but you need to refine a bit the solution.